# SORT Tracker - Parameter Setting

Tags: python, sorting, computer-vision, yolo

I'm having some issues related to the SORT tracker (a combination of Kalman filter and Hungarian algorithm), combined with YOLO v3, in soccer videos. 
As also mentioned in the main paper, SORT suffers a lot about identity switches (in other words, the ID changes even if the tracked object is the same), also in absence of occlusions! I was wondering if i can (slightly) mitigate this problem by calibrating the parameters max_age (the time that can pass without the id assignment) and max_hits. How can these parameter affect the final tracking? And the IoU parameter of Hungarian? Thanks a lot!

```py
class Sort(object):
  def __init__(self,max_age=8,min_hits=3):
    """
    Sets key parameters for SORT
    """
    self.max_age = max_age
    self.min_hits = min_hits
    self.trackers = []
    self.frame_count = 0

  def update(self,dets):
    """
    Params:
      dets - a numpy array of detections in the format [[x,y,w,h,score],[x,y,w,h,score],...]
    Requires: this method must be called once for each frame even with empty detections.
    Returns the a similar array, where the last column is the object ID.

    NOTE: The number of objects returned may differ from the number of detections provided.
    """

    # prevent "too many indices for array" error
    if len(dets)==0:
      return np.empty((0,5))

    self.frame_count += 1
    #get predicted locations from existing trackers.
    trks = np.zeros((len(self.trackers),5))
    to_del = []
    ret = []
    for t,trk in enumerate(trks):
      pos = self.trackers[t].predict()[0]
      trk[:] = [pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3], 0]
      if(np.any(np.isnan(pos))):
        to_del.append(t)
    trks = np.ma.compress_rows(np.ma.masked_invalid(trks))
    for t in reversed(to_del):
      self.trackers.pop(t)
    matched, unmatched_dets, unmatched_trks = associate_detections_to_trackers(dets,trks)

    #update matched trackers with assigned detections
    for t,trk in enumerate(self.trackers):
      if(t not in unmatched_trks):
        d = matched[np.where(matched[:,1]==t)[0],0]
        trk.update(dets[d,:][0])

    #create and initialise new trackers for unmatched detections
    for i in unmatched_dets:
        trk = KalmanBoxTracker(dets[i,:])
        self.trackers.append(trk)
    i = len(self.trackers)
    for trk in reversed(self.trackers):
        d = trk.get_state()[0]
        if((trk.time_since_update < 1) and (trk.hit_streak >= self.min_hits or self.frame_count <= self.min_hits)):
          ret.append(np.concatenate((d,[trk.id+1])).reshape(1,-1)) # +1 as MOT benchmark requires positive
        i -= 1
        #remove dead tracklet
        if(trk.time_since_update > self.max_age):
          self.trackers.pop(i)
    if(len(ret)>0):
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you raise the max_age you are risking confusion between objects which were lost/got out of scene and new objects which get into the last seen area. You should play with this parameter (maybe raise it a bit) and lower the IOU for the Kalman. This would create longer and more robust tracking with an increased risk of different IDs merging into one track. This tuning is essential for your tracker's performance and is highly data dependent. Good luck :)